Multiple concurrent MQTT subscribers
I'm trying to run multiple pub - multiple sub messages exchange.
The problem arises when I'm trying to start multiple subs (the idea was to subscribe to different topic for each subscriber).
I open 2 terminals: one for pubs and one for subs.
Here the code for sub:
import random
from paho.mqtt import client as mqtt_client
import threading

broker='172.18.0.3'
port = 1885
topics = ["sensors/humidity","sensors/temperature"]
# Generate a Client ID with the subscribe prefix.
client_id = f'subscribe-{random.randint(0, 100)}'

# ++ OBJECT ORIENTED PROGRAMMING?

def connect_mqtt() -> mqtt_client:
    def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
        if rc == 0:
            print("Connected to MQTT Broker!")
        else:
            print("Failed to connect, return code %d\n", rc)

    client = mqtt_client.Client(client_id)
    # client.username_pw_set(username, password)
    client.on_connect = on_connect
    client.connect(broker, port)
    return client

def subscribe(client: mqtt_client, topic):
    
    def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
       
        print(f"Received `{msg.payload.decode()}` from `{msg.topic}` topic")

    client.subscribe(topic)
    client.on_message = on_message

def run():
    threads=[]
    for topic in topics:
        
        client = connect_mqtt()
        subscribe(client, topic)
        
        thread=threading.Thread(target=client.loop_forever)
        
        threads.append(thread)

    for thread in threads:
        
        thread.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()


It seems like it's not working as I wanted, since it probably reconnects everytime. Instead, I'd like them to stay awake forever, waiting for me to send them messages through another terminal where I run the pub Python code.
Where is the problem? Is there any smarter way to achieve this goal? I'm kinda fresh into MQTT so maybe I'm not facing the problem in the right way.

You are not starting the MQTT client event/network loop anywhere in your code
I suggest you read the Paho documentation about the different ways to run the event/network loop here https://eclipse.dev/paho/files/paho.mqtt.python/html/index.html#network-loop.
The simplest option would probably be to add client.loop_start() after the client.connect() call.
You should also move the connect_mqtt() function outside the loop subscribing to topics, you only need one client (and since you are reusing the generated client id, the you will just get in an evil reconnect loop, very quickly.
I also suggest you read the full doc for the client.subscribe() function, since you can pass the whole array of topics to it in one go and discard the whole loop to start with. This is because there's very rarely a good reason to run multiple clients in a single application, a single client can subscribe to many topics.
